# Natural sort with Dynamic Linq including multiple sorting parameters

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dynamic-linq

As the title describes, is there any way I can achieve natural sort using Dynamic Linq including support for multiple sorting parameters?

Preferably I would like to do something like this (using a custom IComparer):

```
List<Invoice> invoices = Provider.GetInvoices();

invoices = invoices
  .AsQueryable()
  .OrderBy("SortingParameter1 ASC, SortingParamaeter 2 ASC", new NaturalSort())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: _DynamicLinq_ does not have method `OrderBy` that takes _IComparer_ as parameters, so you can't pass custom comparer, but you can modify source how you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*DynamicLinq* does not have method `OrderBy` that takes `IComparer<T>` as parameters, so you can't pass custom comparer, but you can modify source like this

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T,ComparerType>(this IQueryable<T> source, IComparer<ComparerType> comparer, string ordering, params object[] values)
{
    return (IQueryable<T>)OrderBy((IQueryable)source, comparer, ordering, values);
}

public static IQueryable OrderBy<ComparerType>(this IQueryable source, IComparer<ComparerType> comparer, string ordering, params object[] values)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (ordering == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ordering");
    ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] {
        Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "") };
    ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(parameters, ordering, values);
    IEnumerable<DynamicOrdering> orderings = parser.ParseOrdering();
    Expression queryExpr = source.Expression;
    string methodAsc = "OrderBy";
    string methodDesc = "OrderByDescending";
    foreach (DynamicOrdering o in orderings)
    {
        queryExpr = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), o.Ascending ? methodAsc : methodDesc,
            new Type[] { source.ElementType, o.Selector.Type },
            queryExpr, Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(o.Selector, parameters)), Expression.Constant(comparer));
            methodAsc = "ThenBy";
            methodDesc = "ThenByDescending";
        }
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(queryExpr);
}
```

and use it like this

```
List<Invoice> invoices = Provider.GetInvoices();

invoices = invoices.AsQueryable()
                   .OrderBy(new NaturalSort(), "SortingParameter1 ASC, SortingParamaeter 2 ASC")
                   .ToList();
```

where `NaturalSort` should implement `IComparer<T>`
about implementing narural sort you can see this [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp?lq=1)

**NOTE:** but i'm not sure that this will be work with other providers, like db

Comment: @Philip, I want to once again draw attention to the fact that I'm not sure that it will work with the database

Comment: It's OK cause I´m only using it to sort objects in ILists.
One weird thing though. It's working perfectly on my developing maching but when I publish it I get the following exception: "No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.". 

All the dll's are up to date.

Comment: @Philip, can you see in dll with `DynamicLinq` if there this method? also where you add this code? in source and recompile it? or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I added your code to the DynamicQueryable class in System.Linq.Dynamic namespace so your methods are in there with all the other Dynamic Linq-methods. Very strange..

Comment: @Philip, try compare dll from developer machine with dll after publish, also possibly after publish you have reference on defferent dlls

Comment: Solved it! My IComparer only implemented IComparer<string> and one the sort fields was of type int?. Why it worked in debugging I don't know.

Comment: @Philip possibly different class or query on development and after publish :-)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you want this:

```
invoices = invoices
    .OrderBy(invoice => invoice.SortingParameter1, new NaturalSort())
    .ThenBy(invoice => invoice.SortingParameter2, new NaturalSort())
    .ToList();
```

Basically, you want to use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` for the first sorting parameter, and then `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending` for the rest of them.

(Note that `AsQueryable` is not needed here, as `List<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`.)

Comment: No sorry thats not what I want. I want to use the sortingparameters as strings since the parameters will be unknown until runtime. Dynamic Linq makes this work, however I cant find a way to use a custom IComparer to be able to achieve "Natural sort" / "Natural Numeric Sort".